# I got a validation pipe's error when am passing email and password in the body of the postman

Tags: typescript, validation, pipe, postman, nestjs

Here is the screenshot of error:

[image]

Here is the code of DTO:

```
import {IsString, IsInt,IsEmail,IsNotEmpty, IsNumberString, IsIn} from 'class-validator'

export class logindto{
    @IsEmail()
    username:String

    @IsNotEmpty()
    password:String
}
```

Here is the code of controller:

```
@Post('login')
log(@Body('username')username:logindto,@Body('password')password:logindto):any{
    return this.crudservice.loginsys(username,password)
}
```

Here is the code of services:

```
export class CrudService {
    constructor(@InjectModel('student') private readonly student:Model<studentmodel>){} 

    async loginsys(username,password):Promise<any>{
            const cred=this.student.findOne({username:username,password:password})
            return cred
    }
}
```

Here is the  code of model:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'


export const studentschema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{type:String,required:true},
    std:{type:Number},
    rollno:{type:Number},
    section:{type:String},
    username:{type:String},
    password:{type:String}
});

export interface studentmodel  extends mongoose.Document{
   readonly name:String,
   readonly std:Number,
   readonly rollno:Number,
   readonly section:string,
   readonly username:string,
   readonly password:string
}
```

I already passed header of form-data:application/x-www-url-form-encoded or application/json.But still got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By having strings inside of your `@Body()` decorators, you are telling nest to find the `'username'` property of `req.body`, but you are also saying that `req.body.username` should be a `logindto`, so class-validator is expecting to find `req.body.username.username` and `req.body.username.password` along with `req.body.password.username` and `req.body.password.password`. To fix this, remove the strings from the `@Body()` decorator. If you need to get the username and password separately, you can use object deconstruction, but I would suggest doing that *outside* of the signature, in the body of the method.

```js
@Post('login')
log(@Body()login:logindto,):any{
    const { username, password } = login; // <-- deconstructing the incoming payload
    return this.crudservice.loginsys(username,password)
}
```

Comment: i tried your method but i got the error : CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ username: 'xyz20@test.com', password: 'xyz@1234' }" at path "password" for model "student"

Comment: What does model `student` have anything to do with this? That sounds like a completely different issue

Comment: i added code of my schema and model,and also update my service's code,how am using studentmodel

Comment: I still don't know what exactly you did in regards to my advice and what's failing about it now. Did you use any deconstrcutring? Are you still using multiple `@Body()` decorators? Have you checked the values of username and password in your controller or service?

Comment: i just remove the 'username' and 'password' which i written in the @Body() decorator.Yes am using multiple @Body() decorator for my username and password,Which i written like this @Body()username:logindto,@Body()password:logindto like this.My main purpose is that to use validation pipes for username and password.When am applying validation pipes i got error which i mentioned in my question.When i remove the pipes i got desired output.My issue is that when am applying pipes i didn't get the desired output

Comment: Okay, so now you're assigning {username, password} to both `username` and `password`. What you need to do is use some deconstructing in the controller method. I've updated the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: if you don't mind ,can you please write the proper code of services and controller.It would be very helpful for me.By this way i can figure out where i did wrong in the code.Please provide code if possible.

Comment: If you replace the your post method with what I have given, there should be no problems. I am just giving back what I was given in the first place. If you have more questions, I'd suggest joining the Nest Discord server for more fluent conversations

Comment: thanks alot,it's working now.Thanks for correcting me

Comment: What is nest discord server ? I want to join this to solve more nestjs issues in future.